# MongoDb: Insert or update multiple documents with a unique index

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongojs

I have a MongoDB collection with a unique index.
I am trying to insert or update an array of documents into that collection.

If there is NO existing document in the collection matching the unique index of the document, that new document should be inserted into the collection.

However, if there IS already a document in the collection with that unique index, it should be updated with the fields of the new document. Any fields that are NOT present in the new document should be left untouched.

This is what I have currently which is working for inserting (but NOT for updating).

```
const mongojs = require('mongojs');
const db = mongojs('mongodb://username:password@address.mlab.com:37230/database');

             // items is an array of documents
db.items.insert(items, (err, task) => {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err);
    }
  })
```

I understand this is wrong and it currently gives this error:

> E11000 duplicate key error index: database.items.$upc_1 dup key:

What is the proper query for this?

Comment: Are you getting an error message?

Comment: First, just use the native NodeJS driver form MongoDB. Second, you want to use Upsert, not insert.

Comment: Wasn't clear from your original post that you are using the native driver. mongojs is an NPM module in and of itself. You should show your `required` statements in your examples.

Comment: Re-reading your post, you might still need to catch the error because your index is not the primary key, but a `custom` index.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't believe that you can update an entire array of documents at the same time. Therefore, you would have to update each item in the array individually.

```
items.forEach((item) => {
   db.items.update({_id: item._id}, item, {upsert: true}, (err, task) => {
           if (err) {
             console.log(err);
           }
   });
}
```

The `{upsert: true}` option will update if a record exists and insert if not.

Comment: Thank Tyler. I'm currently using mLab which is a remote hosted service. If I have ten documents, with this approach I have to make ten separate calls. Is there no better way?

Comment: If you could also take at this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42990854/mongodb-insert-multiple-documents-into-collection-with-unique-index-even-if-som

Comment: Not to my knowledge. There is an updateMany function, but it will update all documents that match the given query selector. I don't believe this is what you are looking for.

Comment: This answer appears to ignore that the question is about using the already-defined unique index on the collection, *not* the _id.

Answer (score 5):

You can try using mongodb `bulkWrite` api:

```
var ops = []

items.forEach(item => {
    ops.push(
        {
            updateOne: {
                filter: { _id: unique_id },
                update: {
                    $set: { fields_to_set_if_exists },
                    $setOnInsert: { fileds_to_insert_if_does_not_exist }
                },
                upsert: true
            }
        }
    )
})

db.collections('collection_name').bulkWrite(ops, { ordered: false });
```

Comment: even fields not exist $set operator performs its operations, your $set operator descripton is wrong : https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/set/

Answer (score 0):

What are you looking for is an upsert, not an insert. It can be done by the following code:

```
db.collection.update(
   <query>,
   <updates>,
   {
     upsert: <boolean>,
     multi: <boolean>,
     writeConcern: <document>,
     collation: <document>
   }
)
```

Query will search for a document using the parameters of the query, if it finds, it will update the fields mentioned in . If it doesn't find, it will insert a new document with the fields and values of .

The last object (with multiple fields), contains a field to say if an upsert is desired and one called "multi" to say if an update on multiple documents is desired.

For example:

```
db.items.update({name:"item1"},{$set:{price:20}},{upsert:true})
```

This will search for a document with the name "item1" and set its price to 20. If it doesn't find, it will create a new one with price 20.

One thing to be noticed though is:

If you don't use the tag $set on the fields, it will substitute the whole document.

Supposing you have a document like this:

```
{_id:"1234",name:"item1",price:10}
```

If you run the following two queries:

```
db.items.update({name:"item1"},{$set:{price:20}},...)
```

and

```
db.items.update({name:"item1"},{price:20},...)
```

it will yeld different results:

First one:

```
{_id:"1234",name:"item1",price:20}
```

Second one:

```
{_id:"1234",price:20}
```

If you don't call `$set`, it will change the whole document.

More information on the manual:

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.update/

Hope my answer was helpful

Comment: Thanks, but is only for one document? I have an array of documents.

Comment: updating my answer now

Comment: This is great! But my question is how to do this for an array of documents.

Comment: Is it an array of ids?

Comment: It look like this: [ {"F1": "1", "F2": "1"}, {"F1": "2", "F2": "2"}, {"F1": "3", "F2": "3"}]. F1 is the unique index.

Comment: I see three documents there, is it all destined to the same id? Because since they have the same field names, the last update will be the one that will take effect in the end