# MongoDB: Insert multiple documents into collection with unique index even if some violate the index

Tags: node.js, mongodb, unique, mongojs, database

I am trying to insert an array of documents into a MongoDB collection. The collection has a unique index on one of the fields. I am inserting all the documents at once as such:

```
const mongojs = require('mongojs');
const db = mongojs('mongodb://username:password@address.mlab.com:37230/database');

             // documents is an array of documents
db.items.insert(documents, (err, task) => {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err);
    }
  })
```

Now there is one document that violates the unique index and I receive this error:

> E11000 duplicate key error index: database.items.$upc_1 dup key:

Consequently, NONE of the documents get saved even though there was only one document that violated the unique index.

How do I tell Mongo to just ignore that one document and save all the others? Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `db.collection.insertMany()` function with the parameter `{ordered: false}`. See the docs (near the bottom where they describe unordered inserts): https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.insertMany/